# Azure Dev-ops Pipeline - Conditional execution of task

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have a Azure Pipline which are using to deploy our code. ( it's related to BigData).

There are few tasks which we don't need to deploy every-time. We need to do that only if some of the files have changed. and so I was thinking following.

- Through git command check if particular file(s) have been changed in last commit.
- if so, set particular variable to `true` else `false`
- Now, for deployment task, use `custom condition` and check above variable for `true`

**The problem** 
I am not able to execute `git command` as artifacts are being copied from `build pipeline` which doesn't have `.git` directory.

I tried to clone a git directory, however, the credential is configured in a way that I can't clone it.

is there a different way to solve this problem.

> I.e execute certain task in release pipeline only if particular file(s) have been changed.

Comment: Be careful with the "last commit" parameter to your intended solution. Any given build can have any number of commits, and I don't think you can enforce only one. You'll want to use `git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $change.id` where `$change` is the current item in an iteration of all commits for the current build/release.

Comment: Hi, how the things going? Does Bevan's answer could help you ? If yes, you can accept the answer thus other SO users will be able to see whether the solution works. If you still facing some issues, feel free to leave commend here :-)

Answer (score 1):

### Tl;Dr There are lots of ways to stitch this together

1. Add git repo to your release pipeline artifacts as @Shayki mentioned
2. Add git repo to your release pipeline manually with the `--no-checkout` option
3. Do git operations in the build and include some flag file in the artifact
4. Do git operations in the build and tag the build (preferred)
5. Push the `.git` dir into the artifact

### Add git repo to your release pipeline artifacts

Adding the Git repository as an artifact to your release pipeline will allow the deployment agent access to the source control (including code files) so that you can do the query in the release stage in question.

### Add git repo to your release pipeline manually

I don't think the Azure DevOps UI is going to give you the option to clone only the `.git` directory, which would prevent your deployment agent from actually having the source code. But, if you "allow scripts to access oAuth token" you should be able to use that to clone the repository manually via powershell using `git clone --no-checkout url`.

### Include some flag file in the artifact

Other routes would be to do the decision making on the build pipeline producing the artifact, and publish a switch file with your artifact that indicates the release should(n't) perform expected task(s).

### Tag the build

There may be a different way to do this but I don't know it. Use the RESTapi to [add a tag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/tags/add%20build%20tag?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to the build if the search in git indicates that the release needs to do the extra work. Don't forget to set the "allow scripts to use oAuth token" on your build job. Then create a `Full` and `Min` stage in your release pipeline, where full has the extra task(s) and min doesn't.

[image]

With these stages you could employ the artifact filters feature based on the build tag.
[image]

---

[image]

If you don't want to (or can't) use separate stages and employ the artifact filters, you can [get the tags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/tags/get%20build%20tags?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) via powershell and use the custom conditions you mentioned in your question.

### Push the `.git` dir into the artifact

If you're completely bent on doing the decision on the release pipeline, and you cannot get access to the repo from there, push the `.git` directory from your build into the (a new?) artifact, and then use it on the release pipeline. (This seems like a real hack, and I'm not totally sure it would work).

Answer (score 1):

I've found 2 ways to acheive this. I use Powershell but change for whatever flavour you prefer.

In your Build pipeline run your git diff:

```
$CSV_FileName = git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only $Commit_ID -r | where {$_ -like "*.csv"}
$Ps1_FileName = git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only $Commit_ID -r | where {$_ -like "*.ps1"}
```

Then run your condition

### Method 1

Add a Build Tag then set this as a stage condition in Release. My preferred method for Stage control.

**Build**

```
#Set Build Tag
if ($CSV_FileName) {
 Write-Host "##vso[build.addbuildtag]CSV"
}
if ($PS1_FileName) {
 Write-Host "##vso[build.addbuildtag]PS1"
}
```

**Release**

```
Stage Artifact Filter: Branch | Include | <TagName>
```

### Method 2

Bind a Variable Group do both your Build and Release Pipelines. This allows more granular control with conditions per task, but is a bit more clunky. Make sure you reset you Variable in the Variable group at the end of your Release.

**Build**

```
#Update Variable Group
if ($CSV_FileName) {
 echo $env:AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT | az devops login
 az devops configure -d organization=https://dev.azure.com/<your_organisation>/ project=<your_project>

 az pipelines variable-group variable update --id <id_here> --name <name_here> --value <value_here>
}
if ($PS1_FileName) {
 echo $env:AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT | az devops login
 az devops configure -d organization=https://dev.azure.com/<your_organisation>/ project=<your_project>

 az pipelines variable-group variable update --id <id_here> --name <name_here> --value <value_here>
}
```

**Release**

```
Task Condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['VariableName'], 'Value'))
```

Comment: Method2 seems exactly what I am looking for. However, in method1 I am not getting this part `Stage Artifact Filter: Branch | Include | <TagName>` could you explain it a bit

Comment: I've just had a closer look at Josh's answer and there's a screenshot there under "Tag the build"

Answer (score 0):

You can add the git repo as additional artifact:

[image]

Comment: you mean as part of a `task` in `release` pipeline ?  and how this is going to help me ?

Comment: No part of a task, you want the git repo during the release (but you didn't success to clone it) so you can add the repo as an artifact, it will be downloaded at the beginning of the release, so add a task that does your 3 steps.